Cannot format date to March 19, 2024 at 11:06:32 AM UTC+5" type in flutter
I want to format my DateTime.now() to March 19, 2024 at 11:06:32 AM UTC+5" but its Data type should be DateTime.
I am getting Date in that format but it is in String:
String formattedDate = DateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy 'at' hh:mm:ss a 'UTC+5'").format(DateTime.now().toUtc().add(Duration(hours: 5)));

So, i want that String in DateTime Data Type which i am unable to do.

By the way, DateTime.now().toUtc() can now just be written DateTime.timestamp().

Yeah, thanks for that. But do you know the answer of my question?

I'm not aware of any built-in way to print UTC offsets nicely, so I think you'll have to format DateTime.timeZoneOffset manually:
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

extension on DateFormat {
  String formatWithOffset(DateTime dateTime) {
    var offset = dateTime.timeZoneOffset;
    var offsetStringParts = ['UTC'];
    if (offset != Duration.zero) {
      if (offset.isNegative) {
        offsetStringParts.add('-');
        offset = -offset;
      } else {
        offsetStringParts.add('+');
      }

      if (offset.inMinutes % 60 == 0) {
        offsetStringParts.add('${offset.inHours}');
      } else {
        offsetStringParts
          ..add('${offset.inHours}'.padLeft(2, '0'))
          ..add('${offset.inMinutes % 60}'.padLeft(2, '0'));
      }
    }

    return '${format(dateTime)} ${offsetStringParts.join()}';
  }
}

/// A [DateTime] object that overrides [timeZoneOffset].
class FakeDateTime extends DateTime {
  @override
  Duration timeZoneOffset = Duration.zero;

  FakeDateTime.from(DateTime original)
      : super(
          original.year,
          original.month,
          original.day,
          original.hour,
          original.minute,
          original.second,
          original.millisecond,
          original.microsecond,
        );
}

void main() {
  var now = FakeDateTime.from(DateTime.now());
  var format = DateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy 'at' hh:mm:ss a");

  // Prints: 2024-04-21 12:55:15.138
  print(now);

  // Prints: April 21, 2024 at 12:55:15 PM UTC
  print(format.formatWithOffset(now));

  // Prints: April 21, 2024 at 12:55:15 PM UTC+5
  now.timeZoneOffset = const Duration(hours: 5);
  print(format.formatWithOffset(now));

  // Prints: April 21, 2024 at 12:55:15 PM UTC-0715
  now.timeZoneOffset = -const Duration(hours: 7, minutes: 15);
  print(format.formatWithOffset(now));
}

The formatWithOffset implementation could be simplified by removing the different formatting cases (currently it handles time zone offsets of zero, time zone offsets with a whole number of hours, and time zone offsets with a non-zero minute component differently).
Note that if you want to handle DateTime objects in a time zone other than the local time zone, you probably should be using TZDateTime objects from package:timezone instead:
import 'package:timezone/timezone.dart' as tz;
import 'package:timezone/data/latest.dart' as tz;

void main() {
  tz.initializeTimeZones();

  // See: <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones>
  var location = tz.getLocation('Asia/Karachi');
  var dt = tz.TZDateTime(location, 2024, 3, 19, 11, 6, 32);
  print(dt); // Prints: 2024-03-19 11:06:32.000+0500
}


Thanks for the code, but its that extension is returning a string but i want DateTime.

@AneesDahot Then your request is nonsensical. You asked to format a DateTime object in a certain way. Formatting necessarily produces a String.  Furthermore, DateTime objects already store a time zone offset, so it's unclear what you're asking for.  As I stated, if you want to be able to set an arbitrary time zone on a DateTime object, then you should be using the TZDateTime subtype.

Can you give a code example of TZDateTime that how exactly can i have DateTime in March 19, 2024 at 11:06:32 AM UTC+5 format? it would be helpful.

@AneesDahot I've updated my answer to include an example of how to create a TZDateTime that represents that specified point in time with a UTC+5 offset.  But, as I alluded to before, a specific format makes sense only for a String representation.

k. thanks for code.
